# Replacing ? with # in url to avoid cache busting

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I discovered the UTM variables for Google Analytics bust our page caching. Google Analytics allows using hash instead of question mark, so

```
http://www.example.com/?utm_source=source&utm_medium=medium
```

and

```
http://www.example.com/#utm_source=source&utm_medium=medium
```

Are actually the same. But, as I said, the first option busts our caching while the second does not.

When we generate our own links, then I use `#`. However, services like Feedburner or `dlvr.it` append the UTM campaign variables with a `?` -- so I want in `.htaccess` to redirect all `/?utm...` to `/#utm...`

I know that `NE` (No Escape) should be used for the hash, but I honestly can't figure out how the rewrite condition and rule should be like.

The rule logic should be -

```
RewriteCond: if {path}?{query_string} AND {query_string} has 'utm_source' as a variable,
RewriteRule: redirect to {path}#{query_string} [R,NE,L]
```

Can anyone help me with this place?

Answer (score 1):

OK, I got a eureka shortly after asking the question...

The solution is:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} utm_source
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}#%{QUERY_STRING}? [R,NE,L]
</IfModule>
```

Tested and works...